# unable to click when horizontal bar value is 0 in RGraph

Tags: angular, rgraph

I am using RGraph in my Angular 7 application.

while using horizontal bar graph i am unable to click when the bar value is zero.

i have tried tooltipsHotspotYonly: true and tooltipsHotspotXonly: true

Please let me know if anyone have answer for this.

Comment: Have you inspected the DOM and verified that there is a clickable element ?

Comment: i have used tooltipsHotspotYonly for vertical 3d bar chart  and it is working, but in case of horizontal 3d bar chart tooltipsHotspotXonly is not working when the bar value is zero(i have not inspected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bar chart has the **tooltipsHotspotXOnly** to facilitate this. The HBar has no such property though - so I've added one in - **tooltipsHotspotYOnly**. The replacement **getShape()** function is this:

```
//
// This function can be used to get the appropriate bar information (if any)
// 
// @param  e Event object
// @return   Appriate bar information (if any)
//
this.getShape = function (e)
{
    var mouseXY = RGraph.getMouseXY(e);

    //
    // Loop through the bars determining if the mouse is over a bar
    //
    for (var i=0,len=this.coords.length; i<len; i++) {

        var mouseX = mouseXY[0],  // In relation to the canvas
            mouseY = mouseXY[1],  // In relation to the canvas
            left   = this.coords[i][0],
            top    = this.coords[i][1],
            width  = this.coords[i][2],
            height = this.coords[i][3],
            idx    = i;



        // Recreate the path/rectangle so that it can be tested
        //  ** DO NOT STROKE OR FILL IT **
        if (properties.tooltipsHotspotYonly) {
            this.path(
                'b r % % % %',
                this.marginLeft, top, this.canvas.width - this.marginRight - this.marginLeft, height
            );
        } else {
            this.path(
                'b r % % % %',
                left,top,width,height
            );
        }

        if (this.context.isPointInPath(mouseX, mouseY)) {

            if (RGraph.parseTooltipText) {
                var tooltip = RGraph.parseTooltipText(properties.tooltips, i);
            }

            var indexes = RGraph.sequentialIndexToGrouped(idx, this.data);
            var group   = indexes[0];
            var index   = indexes[1];

            return {
                object: this,
                     x: left,
                     y: top,
                 width: width,
                height: height,
       sequentialIndex: idx,
               dataset: group,
                 index: index,
                 label:  properties.yaxisLabels && typeof  properties.yaxisLabels[group] === 'string' ?  properties.yaxisLabels[group] : null,
               tooltip: typeof tooltip === 'string' ? tooltip : null
            };
        }
    }
};
```

Now you can either:

1. If you're comfortable editing the HBar library, take the code here and
   replace the **getShape()** function in your *RGraph.hbar.js* file.
2. Download the updated library from here:

   https://www.rgraph.net/tests/canvas.hbar/RGraph.hbar.js

   (it will remain until the next version is available at least - at which
   point you can get the new HBar library from the standard RGraph
   download: https://www.rgraph.net/download.html#stable )
3. Wait until version 5.27 comes out and the **tooltipsHotspotYOnly**
   option it will be a part of RGraph (use the link above).